# Generic update operation in dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Currently I am using the AWS SDK to trigger CRUD operations in my dynamoDB. I have written operations in NodeJS that are generic enough to serve arbitrary input data i.e. no need to specify fields and other params in a hard coded way in the operation itself.

I am currently working on writing a generic update function, and I started writing a non-generic version like so:

```
const updateItem = async (pk, status) => {
  currentTime = Date();
  const params = {
    TableName: "table",
    Key: {
        "pk": pk
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set current_status = :x, updated_datetime = :y",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":x": status,
        ":y": currentTime
    }
  };
  await dynamoClient.update(params).promise();
};
```

But I have a little bit of trouble figuring out how to not having to specify the specific fields of `status` and `currentTime` and instead have all the field-value pairs be inputted by the caller of the function, i.e. support an arbitrary number of field-value pairs as input to 1 given `pk`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal parameterized version. Remove the TS type annotations if you are using JS.

A helper function generates the `UpdateExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` from attribute key-value pairs.

```js
type Keys = Record<'pk' | 'sk', string>; // object with keys of 'pk' or 'sk', string values
type Attributes = Record<string, string>; // object with string keys and string values

const expressions = (attr: Attributes): { updateExp: string; exprAttrVal: Attributes } => {
  const entries = Object.entries(attr);

  const updateExp = 'set ' + entries.map(([k], i) => `${k} = :v${i}`).join(', ');

  const exprAttrVal = entries.reduce((acc, [_, v], i) => {
    acc[`:v${i}`] = v;
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return { updateExp, exprAttrVal };
};
```

Test it:

```js
const testAttributes = { current_status: 'OK', current_time: '2022-10-25T16:53:41.952Z' };

test('Update Expression', () => {
  expect(expressions(testAttributes).updateExp).toBe(
    'set current_status = :v0, current_time = :v1'
  );
});

test('ExpressionAttributeValues', () => {
  expect(expressions(testAttributes).exprAttrVal).toEqual({
    ':v0': 'OK',
    ':v1': '2022-10-25T16:53:41.952Z',
  });
});
```

Use it, changing the `updateItem` signature to accept the key and attribute values.

```js
const updateItem = async (keys: Keys, attr: Attributes) => {
  const { updateExp, exprAttrVal } = expressions(attr);

  const params = {
    TableName: 'table',
    Key: keys,
    UpdateExpression: updateExp,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: exprAttrVal,
  };

  // ...
};
```